# uploading csv fie to ftp server - file empty

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to store a file from my local server on an ftp server.

source file is in my current directory (same as php file)

I run the script with `http://www.server.co.za/kisv2/xmltest/export.php`

file to upload to ftp is `http://www.server.co.za/kisv2/xmltest/exportfile.csv`

destination ftp path is: `ftp://ftp.ftpserver.co.za/LocExports/exportfile.csv`

my ftp login defaults to: `ftp://ftp.ftpserver.co.za`

so I want to copy file from in current directory `exportfile.csv` to `ftp://ftp.ftpserver.co.za/LocExports/exportfile.csv`

My Current syntax is:

```
$source = 'exportfile.csv';  //this is a file in the same directory as my php file. full path is... http://www.server.co.za/kisv2/xmltest/exportfile.csv
$target = '/LocExports/exportfile.csv'; //full path is... ftp://ftp.ftpserver.co.za/LocExports/exportfile.csv

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.ftpserver.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

echo "complete";
```

This gives me error `Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening ASCII mode data connection`. the file does appear on the FTP server but is blank and 0bytes in size.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks and regards

**UPDATE**

```
$source = 'exportfile.csv';  
$target = '/LocExports/exportfile.csv'; 

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");

ftp_pasv($conn, true); 

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_BINARY);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

echo "complete";
```

this still fails with:
`Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening BINARY mode data connection.`

file is created on ftp but empty.

thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `ftp_pasv($conn, true);` after your `ftp_login(...)` .

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

> If when using ftp_put you get the one of the following errors:
>
> Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening ASCII mode data
>   connection
>
> Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening BINARY mode data
>   connection
>
> and it creates the file in the correct location but is a 0kb file and
>   all FTP commands thereafter fail. It is likely that the client is
>   behind a firewall. To rectify this use:
>
> `ftp_pasv($conn, true);`
>
> Before executing any put commands. Took me so long to figure this out
>   I actually cheered when I did :D

Comment: Thanks Alex, tried this with the same result. will update question with my syntax now... tried binary too with same result.

Comment: Who is hosting that server, is it your own or is it a hosting company?

Comment: Hi Alex, it is behind a corporate FTP server that they own. Do you think it is an FTP Server Security issue rather than a scripting issue? if so how do we test for that?

Comment: I am keen to cheer now :-)

Comment: Their ftp server's `PASSIVE` mode is enabled (which is what you need) but they did not open a port range for it on their firewall. Ton confirm this, use your favorite FTP client application, set it to PASSIVE mode, connect to their server and try to upload (manually) the same file. If it doesn't work, either they or you have firewall issues.

Comment: Thanks Alex, gave this a try in Filezill and it went through in passive mode with manual transfer. our code then?

Comment: Are you running your PHP script on the same machine as the one you did the FTP test with ? If not, the firewall problem may well be on the server where that PHP script runs from.

Comment: understood. the ftp client is on my machine and the script is a server(ISP) to server(Corporate Server). Thanks Alex. will revert.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The file created but size 0 KB. after setting mode to passive, my file successfully transferred to FTP Server. 
InFact there are 3 things we have to take care while uploading file on FTP Server.

1. set file type to BINARY: `objFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`
2. set File Transfer Mode to BINARY: `objFtpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`
3. set Mode to Passive (i dont know what it does internally. but it works...!): `objFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();`